# Selectable Epilog in a plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, options, interactive

Can I make an inset graphic added through the Plot option "Epilog" selectable, so that I can fine tune its position in the plot by hand, or is this not possible? If its not does any one have any alternative suggestions for achieving something similar?

I tried this and unsurprisingly it doesn't work:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
     Epilog -> Inset[Text[Style["(a)", 20, Black, 15],
                ContentSelectable->True], Scaled[{0.1, 0.9}]]]
```

Comment: I think the linked topic is what you need. Let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: Yes, that works fine, thank you!